# Delete Files from directory based on file name version

Tags: python

I would like to delete old ZIP files from directory based on file name where date created cant be taken into account

E.g.

```
PyhtonReport_20180404_03.zip
PyhtonReport_20180404_02.zip
PyhtonReport_20180404_01.zip
PyhtonReport_20181221_02.zip
PyhtonReport_20181221_01.zip
PyhtonReport_20180816_01.zip
```

End Result:

```
PyhtonReport_20180404_03.zip
PyhtonReport_20181221_02.zip
PyhtonReport_20180816_01.zip
```

I am tryign to read first 23 characters and if it match with second then compare file1 to file2. If the value is false then append to list and eventually delete it.

```
import os
source = r'C:\Users\Pyhton'
for filename in os.listdir(source):
    GroupFile = filename[0:22]
```

Lost how to keep the value of first file and keep on checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should give you the desired end result.

```
import os

source = r"C:\Users\Pyhton"    
file_names = os.listdir(source)

latest_files = {}
for file_name in file_names:
    name_parts = file_name.split("_")
    date_stamp = name_parts[1]

    if date_stamp not in latest_files or file_name > latest_files[date_stamp]:
        latest_files[date_stamp] = file_name


keep_files = latest_files.values()
for file_name in file_names:
    if file_name in keep_files:
        continue

    os.remove(os.path.join(source, file_name))
```

Create a mapping (`latest_files`) of date: latest_version_file_name and then remove all files but those in the mapping.

Comment: Hi Dusan, Thanks a lot for you help. Unfortunatly this is nto working out and might be we have missed to add date_stamp.  

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
         ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
      <ipython-input-71-e3a4de830318> in <module>
      8     name_parts = file_name.split("_")
      9 
---> 10     date_stamp, version = name_parts[1:]
     11 
     12     if date_stamp not in latest_files or version > latest_files[date_stamp]:
      ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Quite Close. I made small mistake in file name while uploading this, 

Source Files
======================

PyhtonReport_20180404_567_03.zip
PyhtonReport_20180404_567_02.zip
PyhtonReport_20180404_567_01.zip
PyhtonReport_20181221_145_02.zip
PyhtonReport_20181221_145_01.zip
PyhtonReport_20180816_345_01.zip


End Result
=======================

PyhtonReport_20180404_567_03.zip
PyhtonReport_20181221_145_02.zip
PyhtonReport_20180816_345_01.zip

We need to consider 1st and 2nd entries after the split. is it doable?

Comment: Done.. I have added one more string
date_stamp = name_parts[1] + name_parts[2]

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Sorry, i missed the part about keeping some of them!

```
import glob
import os
files = glob.glob('path/to/old/files/common_part_of_files_names*.zip')
groups = set([f[:21] for f in files])
for group in groups:
  versions = [f for f in files if f.starts_with(group)]
  versions.remove(max(versions)) # pop latest
  for v in versions:
    os.remove(v)
```

Comment: Need to add conditions. At this moment, above code simply delete all the files.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I couldn't ressist.

```py
def distinct_dates(files):
    "Remove duplicates of same date files, preserving the first ocurrence"
    o = {}  # Saves first occurrence as {date: file}
    for i, date in enumerate(map(lambda f: f[13:21], files)):
        if date not in o:
            o[date] = files[i]
    return list(o.values())
```

and its usage

```py
files = [
    "PyhtonReport_20180404_03.zip",
    "PyhtonReport_20180404_02.zip",
    "PyhtonReport_20180404_01.zip",
    "PyhtonReport_20181221_02.zip",
    "PyhtonReport_20181221_01.zip",
    "PyhtonReport_20180816_01.zip",
]

print(distinct_dates(files))
```